# How to reuse widgets without doubling the code?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am writing a Python application within jupyter notebook 5.7.8 (using ipywidgets 7.4.2 and pytables 3.5.1) and have the problem of generating several visually identical ui controls (grouped together to several dropdowns, sliders and buttons), which interact with different user data per ui control group.

To avoid writing the same code 18 times (for 18 ui control groups), I wonder how to solve this problem in a generical way, that means writing the code once (like a 'blueprint'), and build up the 18 different ui control groups from that 'blueprint'...?

Here is the code, I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import Layout, HBox, VBox
from IPython.display import clear_output

data_df = pd.DataFrame({
           'SUBJECT': [1,2], 
           'SIDE': ['left', 'right'], 
           'ACTIVITY': [1,2], 
           'DATA': [1,2], 
           'ABS_TIME': [1,2], 
           'REL_TIME': [1,2], 
           'VAL1': [1,2],
           'VAL2': [1,2], 
           'VAL3': [1,2]})


subject_ui_values  = [''] + data_df['SUBJECT'].unique().tolist()
side_ui_values     = [''] + data_df['SIDE'].unique().tolist()
activity_ui_values = [''] + data_df['ACTIVITY'].unique().tolist()
userdata_ui_values = [''] + data_df['DATA'].unique().tolist()
axis_ui_values     = ['', 'ABS_TIME', 'REL_TIME', 'VAL1', 'VAL2', 'VAL3']

# Flag whether to plot data or not
plot_data = True


def update_sample_range_plt1(args):
    # Update value range of slider 'sample_plt1_sldr', if (not empty) values were specified at dropdowns:
    #   'SUBJECT' and 'SIDE' and 'ACTIVITY' and 'USERDATA'
    if ((subject_plt1_drpdwn.value != "") and (side_plt1_drpdwn.value != "") and 
        (activity_plt1_drpdwn.value != "") and (userdata_plt1_drpdwn.value != "")):

        ##### SET / GET UI CONTROL PROPERTIES (SLIDER DESCRIPTION, SLIDER VALUE, ...) #####
        print("")

    else: # If any values in dropdowns 'SUBJECT' and 'SIDE' and 'ACTIVITY' and 'USERDATA' are empty

        ##### SET / GET UI CONTROL PROPERTIES (SLIDER DESCRIPTION, SLIDER VALUE, ...) #####
        print("")


def update_sample_range_plt2(args):
    # Update value range of slider 'sample_plt2_sldr', if (not empty) values were specified at dropdowns:
    #   'SUBJECT' and 'SIDE' and 'ACTIVITY' and 'USERDATA'
    if ((subject_plt2_drpdwn.value != "") and (side_plt2_drpdwn.value != "") and 
        (activity_plt2_drpdwn.value != "") and (userdata_plt2_drpdwn.value != "")):

        ##### SET / GET UI CONTROL PROPERTIES (SLIDER DESCRIPTION, SLIDER VALUE, ...) #####
        print("")

    else: # If any values in dropdowns 'SUBJECT' and 'SIDE' and 'ACTIVITY' and 'USERDATA' are empty

        ##### SET / GET UI CONTROL PROPERTIES (SLIDER DESCRIPTION, SLIDER VALUE, ...) #####
        print("")



def filter_data_df_plt1(_):

    with output1:
        def aux_filter_df(ui_element_value, label_num, data_df, df_column):

            ##### GET / SET UI CONTROL VALUES AND MAKE A QUERY ON A PANDAS DATAFRAME 'data_df'
            print("")

        # Clear output of ipywidget
        clear_output()

        # Display filtered results in jupyter cell (output1)
        display(filtered_data_df_1)


def filter_data_df_plt2(_):

    with output1:
        def aux_filter_df(ui_element_value, label_num, data_df, df_column):

            ##### GET / SET UI CONTROL VALUES AND MAKE A QUERY ON A PANDAS DATAFRAME 'data_df'
            print("")

        # Clear output of ipywidget
        clear_output()

        # Display filtered results in jupyter cell (output1)
        display(filtered_data_df_2)



def plot_filtered_data_plt1():

    ##### PLOT DATA USING VISDOM #####
    print("")


def plot_filtered_data_plt2():

    ##### PLOT DATA USING VISDOM #####
    print("")



def clear_plot_plt1(_):

    ##### CLEAR PLOT IN VISDOM #####
    print("")


def clear_plot_plt2(_):

    ##### CLEAR PLOT IN VISDOM #####
    print("")


# Set output1 of ipywidget 
output1 = widgets.Output()
output2 = widgets.Output()


if plot_data:
    query_plt1_btn_description = 'Query and Plot 1'
    query_plt2_btn_description = 'Query and Plot 2'
else:
    query_plt1_btn_description = 'Query 1'
    query_plt2_btn_description = 'Query 2'


# Define new button ui controls 'query_plt1_btn', 'clear_plt1_btn'
query_plt1_btn  = widgets.Button(description=query_plt1_btn_description)
query_plt2_btn  = widgets.Button(description=query_plt2_btn_description)

clear_plt1_btn  = widgets.Button(description='Clear Plot 1', disabled=True)
clear_plt2_btn  = widgets.Button(description='Clear Plot 2', disabled=True)


# Define new dropdown ui controls
subject_plt1_drpdwn     = widgets.Dropdown(options=subject_ui_values, value='', description='Subject 1:')
side_plt1_drpdwn        = widgets.Dropdown(options=side_ui_values, value='', description='Side 1:')
activity_plt1_drpdwn    = widgets.Dropdown(options=activity_ui_values, value='', description='Activity 1:')
userdata_plt1_drpdwn      = widgets.Dropdown(options=userdata_ui_values, value='', description='User Data 1:')
x_axis_plt1_drpdwn      = widgets.Dropdown(options=axis_ui_values, value='', description='Plot 1 (X):', 
                                           disabled=(not plot_data))
y_axis_plt1_drpdwn      = widgets.Dropdown(options=axis_ui_values, value='', description='Plot 1 (Y):',
                                           disabled=(not plot_data))

subject_plt2_drpdwn     = widgets.Dropdown(options=subject_ui_values, value='', description='Subject 2:')
side_plt2_drpdwn        = widgets.Dropdown(options=side_ui_values, value='', description='Side 2:')
activity_plt2_drpdwn    = widgets.Dropdown(options=activity_ui_values, value='', description='Activity 2:')
userdata_plt2_drpdwn      = widgets.Dropdown(options=userdata_ui_values, value='', description='User Data 2:')
x_axis_plt2_drpdwn      = widgets.Dropdown(options=axis_ui_values, value='', description='Plot 2 (X):', 
                                           disabled=(not plot_data))
y_axis_plt2_drpdwn      = widgets.Dropdown(options=axis_ui_values, value='', description='Plot 2 (Y):',
                                           disabled=(not plot_data))


# Define new slider ui control
sample_plt1_sldr     = widgets.IntRangeSlider(min=1, max=1, value=[1,1], step=1, description='Sample 1:', 
                                         disabled=True, continuous_update=False, orientation='horizontal', 
                                         layout=Layout(width='62%'))

sample_plt2_sldr     = widgets.IntRangeSlider(min=1, max=1, value=[1,1], step=1, description='Sample 2:', 
                                         disabled=True, continuous_update=False, orientation='horizontal', 
                                         layout=Layout(width='62%'))


# Execute function 'filter_data_df_plt1', if 'filter_data_df_plt2' was clicked
query_plt1_btn.on_click(filter_data_df_plt1)
query_plt2_btn.on_click(filter_data_df_plt2)


# Execute function 'clear_plot_plt1', if 'clear_plt2_btn' was clicked
clear_plt1_btn.on_click(clear_plot_plt1)
clear_plt2_btn.on_click(clear_plot_plt2)


# Monitor values of dropdowns, and execute function 'update_sample_range_plt1', if value changed
subject_plt1_drpdwn.observe(update_sample_range_plt1, 'value')
side_plt1_drpdwn.observe(update_sample_range_plt1, 'value')
activity_plt1_drpdwn.observe(update_sample_range_plt1, 'value')
userdata_plt1_drpdwn.observe(update_sample_range_plt1, 'value')

subject_plt2_drpdwn.observe(update_sample_range_plt2, 'value')
side_plt2_drpdwn.observe(update_sample_range_plt2, 'value')
activity_plt2_drpdwn.observe(update_sample_range_plt2, 'value')
userdata_plt2_drpdwn.observe(update_sample_range_plt2, 'value')


# Define layout of ui controls
ui_elements1 = VBox([widgets.VBox([HBox([subject_plt1_drpdwn, side_plt1_drpdwn, activity_plt1_drpdwn]), 
                                  HBox([userdata_plt1_drpdwn, sample_plt1_sldr]),
                                  HBox([x_axis_plt1_drpdwn, y_axis_plt1_drpdwn, clear_plt1_btn]),
                                  HBox([query_plt1_btn])])])

ui_elements2 = VBox([widgets.VBox([HBox([subject_plt2_drpdwn, side_plt2_drpdwn, activity_plt2_drpdwn]), 
                                  HBox([userdata_plt2_drpdwn, sample_plt2_sldr]),
                                  HBox([x_axis_plt2_drpdwn, y_axis_plt2_drpdwn, clear_plt2_btn]),
                                  HBox([query_plt2_btn])])])

# Display ui controls as well as the output1
display(widgets.VBox([ui_elements1, ui_elements2, output1, output2]))
```

[image: Screenshot]

It would be great, if you would provide me with a simple example

Comment: use lists and dicts.

Comment: Could you pleas describe more in detail what do you exactly mean?
Do you have some code that visualizes me a simple example?